# Why aren't my badge counts being accurately reflected?

Tags: support, badges

**UPDATE**: This may just be an issue of my lack of patience. My badge count is up to 13 out of the expected 14 as of now (the Critic badge is the only one missing).

Since posting I've earned the Cleanup badge. No Critic badge still. Count is now 14 out of an expected 15.

---

I noticed there were a few easy to accomplish badges in the bronze category that I could knock out quickly this morning:

- Informed
- Suffrage
- Voxi Populi
- Critic

With this, when I earned Informed, my bronze badge count went from 11 to 12. My badges section in my profile is in concurrence with this:

[image: Screenshot of my badges.]

However, when I open the modal to determine which badge to track next, it shows a total of 14 badges earned. The two that are missing are:

- Suffrage
- Voxi Populi

As you can see in my tracking modal, it clearly states I earned them:

[image: Screenshot of the tracking modal.]

Also, I cast my first accepted downvote on a poorly received question, yet I wasn't awarded the Critic badge:

[image: Screenshot of my first downvote.]

---

I have a few questions related to troubleshooting this issue:

- Is there a limit to the rate at which we can earn badges?
- Are there badges that don't display on our badge counts?
- Why would these badges not display?
- Why wasn't I awarded the critic badge?

The primary question however is why aren't my badge counts being accurately reflected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some badges are not awarded instantly when the corresponding event occurs. Instead, there are batch jobs that run at varying frequencies that check for the conditions and award the badges. After 24 hours, if you still don't have the badge, there may be an actual problem. It will often take less time than that, but it should never take longer

The tracking UI clearly sees a different list of badges than the officially awarded badges. You should officially receive any badges listed there within 24 hours.